# Getting data from table based on time in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime

This query is having some problem.

From 10PM - 08AM (From 2200(Night) to 0800 (Morning))

This query is not working. I know the date changes after 24:00 hours and I think that's the reason the query isn't working.

```
SELECT date(callDate) AS dates,
       sum(calltype = 'MISSED') AS missedCall,
       sum(callType = 'INCOMING') AS incomingCall,
       sum(callType = 'OUTGOING') AS outgoingCall
FROM tbl_call_details
WHERE userId = '1' AND
      date(callDate) BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-31' AND
      time(callDate) > '22:00' AND time(callDate) < '08:00'
GROUP BY date(callDate)
ORDER BY date(callDate) ASC
```

Also tried the below but that is also not working for me.

```
SELECT  * FROM tbl_call_details
WHERE userId = '1' AND
      date(callDate) BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-31' AND
      time(callDate) > '22:00' AND
      time(callDate) < '08:00'
```

I would like to get result between 2200-0800 using select query. If anyone having any idea please kindly guide me.

**This is working very well as I have added 0800-2200 which comes in the same day.**

```
SELECT date(callDate) AS dates,
       sum(calltype = 'MISSED') AS missedCall,
       sum(callType = 'INCOMING') AS incomingCall,
       sum(callType = 'OUTGOING') AS outgoingCall
FROM tbl_call_details
WHERE userId = '1' AND
      date(callDate) BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-31' AND
      time(callDate) > '08:00' AND time(callDate) < '22:00'
GROUP BY date(callDate)
ORDER BY date(callDate) ASC
```

**OUTPUT :-**

```
dates     missedCall    incomingCall    outgoingCall

2014-04-01  0           5           22
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `OR` condition, your query tries to select data where time is before 8 AM and also after 22 PM, which is not possible. Note you need to add the brackets, if you don't add them, the result will be different  (try that yourserlf):

```
SELECT  date(callDate) AS dates, sum(calltype = 'MISSED') AS missedCall, sum(callType = 'INCOMING') AS incomingCall, sum(callType = 'OUTGOING') AS outgoingCall 
FROM tbl_call_details 
WHERE userId = '1' AND date(callDate) BETWEEN '2014-04-01' AND '2014-04-31' 
AND (time(callDate) > '22:00' OR time(callDate) < '08:00') 
GROUP BY date(callDate) ORDER BY date(callDate) ASC
```